# Create checkboxes(table) from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I want to write out details from MySQL database to checkboxes. And the checkboxes structure should look like 6*6 square. ( 6 in one row, 6 in one column).

MySQL database looks like :

```
|id|package|
|1 |HEI    |
|2 |TAG    |
|...|
```

I wrote this function (in php)

```
function getPackages3()
{
    $con = openLockMySQLdb('labcom', 'packages', 'READ');

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT id, package FROM packages ORDER BY package ASC", $con);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
        $packages .= '<ul>' . '<li>' . '<label>' . '<input type="checkbox" class="packages_2" id="tab_packages" name="' . $row['package'] . '" value="' . $row['id'] . '-' . $row['package'] . '">' . '<p class="checkbox_label">' . $row['package'] . '</p>' . '</label>' . '</ul>' . '</li>';
    }

    closeUnlockMySQLdb($con);

    return $packages;
}
```

to get in checkboxes, it's working but i can't but 6 in one row and 6 in one column. So i can't make a square from the checkboxes.

Comment: you're mixing ´mysql_` with `mysqli_`! And of course you _should not_ use `mysql_` at all.

Comment: `</ul>` and `</li>` wrong order at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your database table contains 6 * 6 = 36 entries of packages, right? Then the only problem is to have a kind of 'line feed' after every 6th entry.

I'd prefer a CSS solution in this case and use the `nth-of-type()` selector. But you need to move the `<ul>` tag out of the loop:

```
function getPackages3()
{
    $con = openLockMySQLdb('labcom', 'packages', 'READ');

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT id, package FROM packages ORDER BY package ASC", $con);
    $packages = '<ul>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
        $packages .= '<li>' . '<label>' . '<input type="checkbox" class="packages_2" id="tab_packages" name="' . $row['package'] . '" value="' . $row['id'] . '-' . $row['package'] . '">' . '<p class="checkbox_label">' . $row['package'] . '</p>' . '</label></li>';
    }
    $packages .= '</ul>';

    closeUnlockMySQLdb($con);

    return $packages;
}
```

The CSS would then be like that:

```
li {
    float: left;
}
li:nth-of-type(6n) {
    clear: left;
}
```

I kept your calls to the database functions even if they use mixed libraries (see comments from @jeff) because it is a different problem, but to make it work, you have to fix this as well.

Comment: I fixed the syntax problems (comments from @jeff) . And  tried to use your solution. Now putting in one <ul> all <li> . But i want 6 <ul> which contains 6 <li> per each <ul> . BTW thanks for helping!

Comment: Ok, then it's even easier. Just keep the `li { float: left; }' style and put the `<ul>` tags back in the `while` loop again.

Comment: I solved it . Without  
li:nth-of-type(6n) {
    clear: left;
}
I made a 6*6 with css. Thanks for help.